# Getting error when running appium in a iOS device

Tags: java, ios, appium

I am trying to run Appium on my ios device. I was able to install webdriveragent on my device and the build is ok but when I try to test the connectivity from my java app I am getting below error.

```
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65. 
This usually indicates an issue with the local Xcode setup or WebDriverAgent project configuration or the driver-to-platform version mismatch. 
Consider setting 'showXcodeLog' capability to true in order to check the Appium server log for build-related error messages.. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
```

Here is my Java code to test the connectivity

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "16.6.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "");    

    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "00008030-000000000");
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "xcuitest");
    
    
     driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723"), capabilities);
```